# How to create a hierarchical timeline sort of view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Note :- This question is for the layout and not the custom action bar in the image below

Is it possible to create a timeline sort of view such as in the image. A View may contain inner view and they may very in number.
It may contain any number of elements, list items. A single inner view may extend to the end of the screen. The whole view, inner view are scrollable. It is very complicated. Please give some suggestions

[image]

Comment: You need to create this view dynamically.  It is possible

Comment: The above comment is less constructive. If it could be more specific, it will be better.

Comment: Saying only dynamic will not help, Sorry

Comment: Can anyone post some response ? It is a fairly good problem.

Comment: At a first sight, it seems a very nice custom ExpandableListView. Maybe you can do it implementing such a control.

Comment: @AndroidL Hi this view is from which application? And did you got any solution for this view??

Comment: @RahulGupta Hey, can you tell me application name of this image??

Comment: @PankajKumar - Sorry Cant disclose the name of the app

Comment: @RahulGupta did you succeed in implementing this type of UI?